# does EL Logging have a troubleshooting tool like Nlog internal log?

Tags: enterprise-library, nlog

NLog has an [internal log](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Internal_logging) that the developer can use to troubleshoot issues with logging. Does Enterprise Library Logging have anything like that that I can use to figure out why my log messages aren't going anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "Logging Errors and Warnings" special category. If there's a problem with the logging infrastructure itself, it'll get logged there. You can point this at any trace listener - by default it goes to the Windows event log.

Of course, if you have a problem with the trace listener for the errors, things get lost. There's only so many turtles you can stack on this one.